# Draw a "clean" circle with OpenCV and add a gradient

Tags: c++, opencv, drawing

Consider the MWe below that outputs the following circle:

[image]

as you can see the border is very curly. Do you know how it can somehow be "sharepened"?

I would like to add some gradient to it, so it gets some kind of 3D appearance. The final result should look like the results of the [Photoshop radial gradient](http://helpx.adobe.com/en/photoshop/using/gradients.html). Is there any way to accomplish this with OpenCV?

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
using namespace cv;
void test(){
    Mat m(300,300,CV_8UC3,CV_RGB(255,255,255));
    ellipse(m,Point(150,150),Size(150,150),0,0,120,CV_RGB(0x6C,0x8C,0xD5),-1);
    ellipse(m,Point(150,150),Size(150,150),120,0,120,CV_RGB(0x46,0x71,0xD5),-1);
    ellipse(m,Point(150,150),Size(150,150),240,0,120,CV_RGB(0x06,0x2F,0x6F),-1);
    imshow("WINDOW",m);
    waitKey(0);
}
```

Comment: regarding the ragged border ,`ellipse(m,Point(150,150),Size(150,150),0,0,120,CV_RGB(0x6C,0x8C,0xD5),-1,CV_AA);`

Comment: @muffel  You can see an example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22654770/creating-vignette-filter-in-opencv for how to create gradient.