# OpenCV C++ to calculate vignette effect using gaussian kernel function

Tags: c++, opencv

I try to convert [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22843077/1117968) from python to C++ and I'm stuck on the first call to multiply... 
*small* is my input Mat with 2 dims and about 600x400 cols/rows.

```
Mat a = getGaussianKernel(small.cols, .3);
Mat b = getGaussianKernel(small.rows, .3);
Mat ta;
transpose(a, ta);
Mat c = *new Mat(ta.rows, ta.cols, ta.type());
cv::multiply(ta, b, c);
Mat d;
cv::max(c, d);
d = c / d;
Mat e;
multiply(small, d, e);
```

The error message reads:

> The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function arithm_op

I'm not familiar with either numpy or matplotlib but I'm constraint to C++ for reasons to lengthy to explain...

Comment: Which line is giving you the errors? I'm assuming it's the first call to `cv::multiply`?

Comment: Exactly. I clarified in my questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20multiply(InputArray%20src1,%20InputArray%20src2,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20double%20scale,%20int%20dtype)) for `cv::multiply` you will see that it expects the first two inputs to be the same size and type. This is because it is attempting to do **element-wise multiplication**.

Your Gaussian kernel `a` is defined to be 600 x 1 (which `getGaussianKernel` recommends the first input to be **odd**) so the transpose (`ta`) is going to be 1 x 600.

The second input, `b` is defined to be 400 x 1 (again, should really be an odd size).

Obviously these two are not the same size dimensions/size.

Instead of using `cv::multiply` which is element-wise multiplication, you'll want to just use the `*` operator which is the [matrix product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Matrix_product_.28two_matrices.29) that you likely want.

```
Mat C = b * ta
```

Which should yield a 400 x 600 matrix.

Also, I switched the order of `b` and `ta` so that the matrix dimensions worked out for multiplication.

**Note** you also have some other issues with your code. You're using `cv::max()` to compare an empty matrix with `c`. You should likely use [`cv::minMaxLoc`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#minmaxloc).

The multiplication on your last line looks like it should be fine since you want to apply the combination of Gaussians image directly to the input image on a pixel-by-pixel or element-by-element basis.

Comment: That gives me
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /Users/alexandershishkov/dev/opencv2.4.9/opencv/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp:718: error: (-215) a_size.width == len in function gemm

Comment: Be sure to check my last edit where I switched the order of `b` and `ta`

Comment: With the last comment it seemed to have done the trick. Thanks man.

Comment: minLaxLoc should be minMaxLoc, no? http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#minmaxloc

Comment: @der_michael Yes! Sorry about that! Fixed.

Comment: Also just corrected the last line because you should be using the element-wise multiplication there.