# Remove vignette filter of colored image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am new to Python OpenCV image processing. I want to remove the border/outline shadow of images as shown below. I checked '[how to remove shadow from scanned images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44752240/how-to-remove-shadow-from-scanned-images-using-opencv)' which does not work for me. Is this even possible?

[image: Shadow image example]

Comment: Doesnt it look like brightening the image?

Comment: If I just lighten up the whole image it will look like https://imgur.com/1DureNk .

Comment: Lightening is the increasing the whole pixel values in the same ratio. So if you have a threshold for dark parts and decrease the pixel values of them in small ratio than the normal ratio. This may give good results

Comment: I will give it a try. Thank you

Comment: I will try too, I am also curious how it ll look like. If you get good results please answer the question by yourself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem of border/outline shadows reminded me of the vignette filter. You can have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22654770/creating-vignette-filter-in-opencv) if you want to know more about it. So essentially our task to remove the effect of the vignette filter and then increase brightness.

```
#####VIGNETTE
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('Paris.jpg')
height, width = img.shape[:2]
original = img.copy()
# generating vignette mask using Gaussian kernels
kernel_x = cv2.getGaussianKernel(width, 150)
kernel_y = cv2.getGaussianKernel(height, 150)
kernel = kernel_y * kernel_x.T
mask = 255 * kernel / np.linalg.norm(kernel)

# applying the mask to each channel in the input image
for i in range(3):
    img[:, :, i] = img[:, :, i] * mask


cv2.imshow('Original', original)
cv2.imshow('Vignette', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

To counter the effect change `img[:, :, i] = img[:, :, i] * mask` to `img[:, :, i] = img[:, :, i] / mask`

[image: Result]

Now we need to increase the brightness of the image. For this, we will convert the image to HSV and increase the values of saturation and value matrices. To know about it in more detail you can refer to this [article](https://medium.com/dataseries/designing-image-filters-using-opencv-like-abode-photoshop-express-part-1-8765e3f4495b).

```
#THE FULL CODE
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('shadow.jpg')
original = cv2.imread('bright.jpg')
height, width = img.shape[:2]
# generating vignette mask using Gaussian kernels
kernel_x = cv2.getGaussianKernel(width, 150)
kernel_y = cv2.getGaussianKernel(height, 150)
kernel = kernel_y * kernel_x.T
mask = 255 * kernel / np.linalg.norm(kernel)

test = img.copy()
for i in range(3):
    test[:, :, i] = test[:, :, i] / mask    

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(test, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
hsv = np.array(hsv, dtype = np.float64)
hsv[:,:,1] = hsv[:,:,1]*1.3 ## scale pixel values up or down for channel 1(Lightness)
hsv[:,:,1][hsv[:,:,1]>255]  = 255
hsv[:,:,2] = hsv[:,:,2]*1.3 ## scale pixel values up or down for channel 1(Lightness)
hsv[:,:,2][hsv[:,:,2]>255]  = 255
hsv = np.array(hsv, dtype = np.uint8)
test = cv2.cvtColor(hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)


cv2.imshow('Original_bright', original)
cv2.imshow('Original_dark', img)
cv2.imshow('Result', test)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: Result]

The result compared with the original bright image.

[image: Result without vignette]

How the result would have looked like without the inverse vignette filter.

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you. You were pretty much faster than me. The result looks awesome. Thanks

Comment: Glad you liked it!

Comment: Strange expression: mask = 255 * kernel / np.linalg.norm(kernel), why use frobenius norm ? Seems you just need to fit kernel in range 0-1, thats enough. Just find min and max values in kernel and calc kernel=(kernel-min)/(max-min) or use cv.normalize with cv.NORM_MINMAX flag.

Comment: If I run the `VIGNETTE` code shown above it results in [this](https://imgur.com/hVWEuo9) for some reason. Does someone has the same experience?

Comment: I tried recreating this with scikit image's gaussian filter, but the resulting mask has a apparently random 'shape' (it's not a gradient circle centered on the image). Does any one know how to do this using this library? Also, how did you get to the sigma value for gaussian?